# open multiple dialogs from a select box

Tags: jquery, dialog

I can open a dialog when I click on an option in my select box but when I try to open a second one the first one closes. Can't figure out why it is closing. Any help would be appeiciated.

```
// Builds list of tests in the update dialog
function loadTests(testList) {

    // Creates dropdown with list of active reports

    $(testList).find('test').each(function(index, element) {
        var id   = $(this).find('id').text();
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();

        console.log(id + ':' + name);

        //START: Reports Menu
        $("#reports").append(

                '<option id="' + id + '" value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>'
                )
    });

    $( document ).on("change", "#reports", function(){
        var id   = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
        var name = $(this).val();

        console.log(id + ':' + name);

        var options = {
                id:     id,
                title:  name,
                height: 800,
                width:  600,
                show: {

            effect:   "slideDown",
            duration: 800
        },

        minWidth:  100,
        minHeight: 100,
        resizable: true
        }
        $("#dialog-wrapper").dialog(options).dialog("open").append(

                '<div></div>'
                )
    })

}
```

Comment: can you please provide us with a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can't seem to get any dialog to come up in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/asahart/HF4yr/1/